# SkiaSharp SVG click element get id

Tags: c#, svg, skia, skiasharp

let say i have svg document like this:

```
 "<svg height='300' width='300'><rect class='rect us' id='12212' x='34' y='54' width='20' height='20'/><rect class='rect us' id='12213' x='64' y='54' width='20' height='20'/></svg>
```

Is it possible to hit test SVGElements by given point and get id of this element? If so how can i accomplish this task? I did some googling and can't really find anything.

Comment: it is not web dev with all this js/html/dom or something. I'm writting android app in Xamarin.

Comment: SkiaSharp has support for rendering SVGs and it's working well, I can load svg and get rendered bitmap, now I want to make my rectangle clickable.

Comment: Have you managed to get this working? I need the same thing. thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a [gesture recognizer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/)?